# Class member is not modified globally when changed in lamba - c++

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, pass-by-reference

I’m having an issue with some code I  have written in C++. I have created two classes `MyClass` and `Server`. `MyClass` has member called list of type `std::vector<std::string>`. The `Server` class  has a method called `RegisterRoute` which is used to bind a callback method to a string (API route) and adds the binding to a `std::map` member called `routemap`.  When the server receives a request, it looks up the path in the request url and calls the corresponding function that has been bound.

I instantiate instances of `MyClass` and `Server` called `MyClass::MyObject` and `Server::MyServer` in my main program, I bind a callback lambda to a route using `MyServer.RegisterRoute()`. In this lambda I pass `MyObject` to the lambda by reference, and I call a method that adds and item to the `std::vector<>`.  The issue is that out side of the scope of the lambda, the object does not seem to be modified. Hence each time I call the route, the list seems to be unaffected by previous lambda calls. The form of the lambda is as shown below.

```
[&MyObject](std::string item){
    MyObject.addItem(item);
    MyObject.showList();
}
```

If I call the `MyObject.showlist()` method in the lambda after the `MyObject.addItem()`, the list is shown as modified. However, when I hit a route to show the list (which calls the `MyObject.showlist()`), it shows the original list created when the object before the last `addItem` route was called. Also If I call the addItem method outside the lambda, the list is modified.

```
int main(){
MyClass MyObject("new list"); //Constructor to take string and  add it to std::vector<std::string> list
Server MyServer(4564);       //Constructor to create server and bind port to socket

MyServer.RegisterRoute("/additem",[&MyObject](std::string item){
    MyObject.addItem(item);
    MyObject.show();
    return "added";
});
MyObject.addItem("Dummy Item"); //This item is seen in the list when show list calls
MyServer.StartServer();

return 0;
```

}

I thought that passing the object by reference would allow the modifications made in the lambda to affect the original object,Can someone advise on what I am maybe missing?

EDIT ...
I realised I left out parts of the call chain.

RegisterRoute is used to add a defined callback to an route map.

```
void MyServer::RegisterRoute(std::string route,std::function<std::string(std::string)>routehandle){
    this->routemap.emplace(std::make_pair(route,routehandle));
};
```

The MyServer Class calls the Listen method, which accepts a call back that is executed when an incoming connection is received.

```
void MyServer::StartServer(){
    Listen(httphandle);
};
```

The httphandle is a member function of MyServer which defines how to handle the request.

```
void MyServer::httphandle(char* buffer, int socket){
    char* requestbuffer = buffer;
    std::stringstream datastream,headerstream;

    auto requestline = strtok(requestbuffer,"\n");
    auto header = strtok(nullptr,"\n");
    headerstream << header << "\n";

    while((header != nullptr) && (strlen(header)>1)){
        header = strtok(nullptr,"\n");
        headerstream << header <<"\n";
    }

    auto data = strtok(nullptr,"\n");
    char* reqline[3];

    reqline[0] = strtok (requestline, " \t\n");
    if(routemap.find(reqline[1]) != routemap.end()){
                    auto reponsestring = routemap[reqline[1]](data);
                    write(socket, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17);
                    write(socket, reponsestring.c_str(), strlen(reponsestring.c_str()));
            }
            else    
                write(socket, "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n{\"error\":\"Not Found\"}\n", strlen("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n{\"error\":\"Not Found\"}\n")); //FILE NOT FOUND
}
```

It is in this callback the stored lambda will be executed by the routemap lookup.

I can confirm that the lambda is calling as each time I hit the route i call the showlist method and it shows the item was added. When I call the addItem route again, the list doesn't show the previous ones added.

*I apologise for the bad question format, this is my first question and my code is quite heavy so I was trying to simplify the question.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, the code compiles and runs. I didn't copy and paste so i typed parts directly to the question. But the code does run. My code has `MyClass MyObject("new list");`. So its not a compilation issue

Comment: i fixed it for you, but please next time make sure that the code you post here can be copy/pasted to reproduce the problem you describe (and not something else ;)

Comment: Thanks and I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is almost impossible to say what is wrong: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe8996939e5a441b

Comment: I edited the original post to include more information I hope can shed light. I apologise for the bad format of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After thinking about the process I realised that the issue is not with the lambda, but actually with the socket code. I am using `fork()` to handle a new connection in the `MyServer::Listen()` function. This creates a new child process and copies the parent memory to a new memory segment, but the parent isn't updated as the memory is not shared. Hence each call spawns a new child with the original parent memory. I removed the call to fork and the object is indeed updated after each call and is reflected in subsequent one.

I was thinking about the lambda functions as I introduced them most recently. I will work on finding a way around this child/parent issue.